# javascript processing framework addition NaN

Tags: javascript, processing, nan, numeric, addition

I'm trying to use the javascript processing framework with a html5 canvas, but I have a problem with simple addition of 3 numeric variables and I can't figure it out.
here's the code:

```
var radius = 50.0;

var x, y;
var nX, nY;
var delay = 16.0;

// Simple way to attach js code to the canvas is by using a function
function sketchProc(processing) {


processing.size(200,200);
processing.strokeWeight(10);
processing.frameRate(15);
x = processing.width/2.0;
y = processing.height/2.0;
nx = x;
ny = y;



  // Override draw function, by default it will be called 60 times per second
  processing.draw = function() {

    radius = radius + Math.sin(processing.frameCount/4);

    x+=((nX-x)/delay);
    y+=((nY-y)/delay);

    processing.background(100);

    processing.fill(0,121,184);

    processing.stroke(255);

    processing.ellipse(x,y,radius,radius);
  };


  processing.mouseMoved = function(){
        nX = processing.mouseX;
        nY = processing.mouseY;

    }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
// attaching the sketchProc function to the canvas
var p = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
// p.exit(); to detach it
```

the lines with the addition to x and y must be the problem. I get "NaN" from that expression although it's  3 numerical values. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript identifiers are case-sensitive, so `nx` and `ny` are not the same as `nX` and `nY`:

```
nx = x;
ny = y;

...

x+=((nX-x)/delay);
y+=((nY-y)/delay);
```